# How to get all registered supplementary view kinds of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Is there a way to query UICollectionView instance for its currently registered supplementary view kinds?

I am searching for a solution which doesn't require introduction of additional classes. For example I could subclass UICollectionView and store all registered kinds as user of MyChildUICollectionView class registers them but I would like to query it like:

```
let collectionView = ...
let supViewKinds = collectionView.supKinds()
```

Comment: By kind you mean `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader` or `UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter`?

Comment: Yes, also any other kind user can register with `func register(_ viewClass: Swift.AnyClass?, forSupplementaryViewOfKind elementKind: String, withReuseIdentifier identifier: String)` or `func register(_ nib: UINib?, forSupplementaryViewOfKind kind: String, withReuseIdentifier identifier: String)`. I want to have a set of `elementKind`s.